# Ajax request not sending data to php page but logging in console fine

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I cannot figure out why the data is not getting inserted to my mysql database when it is being logged to the console properly.

My form as follows:

```
<form id="insertForm" type="post">
name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
activity: <input type="text" id="activity" name="activity">
level: <input type="number" id="level" name="level">
<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="add">
</form>
```

My ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#add").click(function(e){
var Data = $("#insertForm").serializeArray();
 console.log(Data);
 $.ajax({
 url : "insert.php",
 type: "POST",
 data : Data,
 success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
 {
$('#msg').html(data);
 }
 });
 $("#msg").slideDown("slow");
 e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

My PHP insert:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'lot_root';
$dbpass = '';
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$activity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['activity']);
$level = $_POST['level'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO lottt ".
       "(name, activity, level) ".
       "VALUES('$name','$activity', '$level')";
mysql_select_db('lot');
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

When i insert the data via the input fields it gets logged to the js console fine like so  `[Object, Object, Object]0: Objectname: "character_name"value: "aSD"__proto__: Object1: Object2: Objectlength: 3__proto__: Array[0]`
but nothing is inserted into the mysql database after a quick check.

Comment: Can you examine the POST request that is sent?

Comment: @TZHX what do you mean by this, sorry for my ignorance and thanks for the response

Comment: i cant see anything wrong on client side, except you need to do e.preventDefault(). On the php side, where is your mysql_query()??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the query to save it. I'll answer it to the `mysql_*` library, even though it is deprecated.

This is how the flow is supposed to go:

```
$con = mysql_connect(....) or die();
mysql_select_db('database');

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$activity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['activity']);
$level = $_POST['level'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO lottt ".
       "(name, activity, level) ".
       "VALUES('$name','$activity', '$level')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo 'saved';
}
```

---

## You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. The library is deprecated.

You should look into using `PDO` or `MySQLi` as they are more modern libraries and while you might have to overcome a hurdle to learn it, being competent in those libraries will do you the world of good!

Resources:

- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)
- [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thankyou very much, I will make sure to switch over to mysqli and look more into PDO.

Comment: My pleasure! I'd suggest PDO, it's a great way!